# What am I doing wrong in this code? It's supposed to run indefinitely, but only loops twice

Tags: java

I have a final string array at the top labeled jokes. I would like the program to ask if the user wants to hear a joke, tell the user the joke, and then ask if they would like to hear another. As of right now, the program will ask if the user wants to hear a joke, tell them the joke, ask them if they would like to hear another, tell them a second joke, and then stop. I would like the program to do this indefinitely as opposed to only twice. Any help or advice I could get would be greatly appreciated, as I'm still a beginner to Java.

```
    Random generator = new Random();
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Want to hear a joke?");


    String response = "yes";

    while (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        response = input.nextLine();
        int yourJoke = generator.nextInt(jokes.length);

        System.out.println(jokes[yourJoke]);

        System.out.println("Pretty funny! Want to hear another?");
        response = input.nextLine();


    }

}
```

}

Comment: `response = input.nextLine();` makes response different, therefore the loop might not run indefinately

Comment: You should only be calling for the input once; at the end of the loop. Then the `while` checks it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should only call `input.nextLine()` once inside of the while loop.
- Why ask for input before the while loop if you're just going to ignore it, if you're going to force the response to be "yes" regardless of the user's choice?

One solution in pseudocode:

```
initialize Scanner
initialize Random
hearAnother = false

prompt: want to hear a joke?
get input
hearAnother = input ignore case is "yes"
if hearAnother
  tell your joke

    do 
      prompt: want to hear another joke?
      get input
      hearAnother = input ignore case is "yes"
      if hear another
        tell random joke
      end if
    while hearAnother is true
    end if
```

Comment: I think it would be more logical to enter the loop in the if statement else he would be asked to hear another joke even if he just declined for the first prompt.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: I would agree except he appears to have two different prompts, one for the first joke and a different one for all the rest. I should have put the do-while inside of the if block, and will do that now.

Answer (score 0):

You program looking for input from user and each input is identified by new line that means as soon as user will press enter button program will capture input.

your program is not displaying input cursor in correct line so you might have pressing enter button to reach to next line to input but as soon as you press enter  program capture the value in that case it found blank as input and terminate as while condition only satisfy with "yes".

Solution
Use arrow key to reach to next line to input. Press enter only after you input the complete string "yes".

The following statement should only be present at the end of while loop as you should ask user for next joke once you displayed first one. So remove this from first position.

```
 response = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: The input cursor might appear that way but if you just type it will move to where your text is being printed; the next line.